LiBr solubility in DCM and other solvents
Is LiBr soluble in DCM? If it is soluble in it, can you please suggest other solvent where LiBr is not soluble?

I seriously doubt it. DCM has some solubility in things like methanol, ethanol, ether, acetone, but you need hard Lewis base coordinating Li and Cl in DCM isn't all that hard.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/18439/61578

The short answer is benzene, toluene or anything else that does not have very electronegative groups, the long answer is that you are in an extreme condition, if you remember the electronegativity of halogens is increasing, fluorine chlorine bromine iodine, that is their order of more electronegative at least, but the property of alkali metals is decreasing, lithium is much less likely to lose its electron than sodium and this in turn than rubidium, in addition lithium is a very light atom and bromine is a very heavy, as a consequence any solvent with electronegative regions such as alcohols, ketones, aldeides or non-brominated halides can slightly dissolve LiBr, just look for a solvent that does not have those atoms, such as benzene or toluene, but yes, DCM does dissolve the BrLi
